# how to optimize performance for C++ object I/O manipulation?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, io

I have an object defined as :

`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> large_obj;`

It can store very large amount of data (containing many rows) and it works pretty well.
However, I want to backup `large_obj` into a file, and in some time later, I will load it again from file to another object.

What is the most optimized method to read/write this object instead of writing each row in a file in a pre-defined structure?

Keeping in mind that:

- Multiple calls to read() are more expensive than single call
- Binary files are faster than text files.

Which save time for object I/O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not really care about the overhead of `read()` and `write()` -- just use a buffered stream and a data format that can be read and written without skipping back and forth in the data stream.

The serialized stream you are writing out should be close enough to your data representation so you can take over large chunks of the data by simple copy, but still abstract enough to allow reconstruction from older versions of the data format or on machines with differing internal representations.

I usually define a header that includes a magic number, a data format version and a set of values that capture the machine specific parts. For your case, that would be

```
struct header {
    char magic[4];
    uint32_t endianness;           // 0x01020304
    uint32_t version;              // incremented when format changes
    // paranoia
    uint8_t char_bit;              // std::numeric_limits<char>::digits
    // sizeofs for all types format is dependent on
    uint8_t sizeof_int;            // sizeof(int)
};
```

When reading back data, you compare the values in the header against what you'd expect -- if a case appears where this does not match, you can add deserialization code that handles this.

For the rows, I'd use an encoding like

```
uint16  string_length;
char    string_data[];        // string_length bytes, padding if odd
uint16  vector_length;
int     vector_data[];        // vector_length ints
```

This can be saved and restored efficiently. When your requirements change, just increment the version number, define a new format and adapt the parser code to create the new in-memory representation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). But remember that this library have bad backward compatibility. After serialization you can just write all archive data into file.

The native way of serialization is using stream operator. This is how `boost::serilization` works inside  in most. You can overload your class members `<<` and `>>` operator to write and read into text formats. But better use elegant and stable solution.

Comment: there is no way to do that if i don't use Boost library ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could try document database. The database engine would partly take care of the performance. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), for example.

It's not possible to have **the most optimized** method. You'd have to consider the trade-offs and measure the performance. Boost.Serialization is a good alternative, but you have to have a clear set of requirements, and at least some performance measurement for your most common use cases.